# Can I use pad_sequence with transformer in Pytorch？

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, transformer-model

I'm trying to use transformer to process some image data (not NLP data), e.g. 480 x 640 images with different sequence length, an example would be [6, 480, 640], [7, 480, 640], [8, 480, 640]. And I would like to put these three sequences into one batch.

However, most tutorials I saw use torchtext to deal with the non-fixed length problem. But since I run the transformer with my own dataset, torchtext is not applicable(is it?). After searching I find pad_sequence can be used to deal with this problem.

However I didn't find any tutorials about using pad_sequence with transformer. Is it applicable？Has anyone try it before?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have 03 images with different dimensions. Applying `pad_sequence` function on them will result as follow:

```py
import torch
from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pad_sequence
image_1 = torch.ones(25, 30)
image_2 = torch.ones(32, 30)
image_3 = torch.ones(29, 30)
images = pad_sequence([image_1, image_2, image_3])
print(images.size())
# torch.Size([32, 3, 30])
```

This remains the same if you are working with 3D images

```py
import torch
from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pad_sequence
image_1 = torch.ones(25, 30, 50)
image_2 = torch.ones(32, 30, 50)
image_3 = torch.ones(29, 30, 50)
images = pad_sequence([image_1, image_2, image_3])
print(images.size())
# torch.Size([32, 3, 30, 50])
```

One thing you should be aware of with this function is that it only works when the images share the `n - 1` dimensions. In other words, if you have something like this:

```py
import torch
from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pad_sequence
image_1 = torch.ones(25, 30, 50)
image_2 = torch.ones(32, 50, 30)
image_3 = torch.ones(29, 31, 50)
images = pad_sequence([image_1, image_2, image_3])
# RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (50) must match the size of tensor b (30) at non-singleton dimension 2
print(images.size())
```

It won't work!

But anyways, since you're working with images, I suggest you to use the `Pad` transformation from torchvision. It works the same as the `pad_sequence` function but with more options. Just follow the [doc](http://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.transforms.Pad.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry for not make my question clear enough. What I'm trying to preocess is sequences of images with same shape. Let's say I have a tensor with batch size of 4, and different length of sequences such as 6, 7, 8, 9 with same image size [480, 640]. Can I use pad_sequence to pad these batch?